# Как сделать div навигации справа?

Tags: bootstrap, html, css

Возникла проблема: почему-то спан 5 показывает ниже спан6, а мне надо, чтобы он был справа на уровне спан6, то есть чтобы навигация была справа вверху.

```
<header>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <a href="#"><img src="image/logo.png" class="logo_img"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="span5">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-pos">
                <li><a href="#">Ваш город</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Клиники</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Врачи</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Диагностика</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Сделайте jsfiddle. И ещё разметки не достаточно, нужны стили (CSS), чтобы понять, что к чему.

Comment: Это бутстрап

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, вы смотрите на ширине браузера меньше 767px, а у бутстрапа при таком размере любой спан это 100% ширины: http://jsfiddle.net/s8m1656y/